# Why an error occurs after I modified my model class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

My Vouchers model was like

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Code { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> PackageId { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> ResellerId { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> AddedDT { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> RedeemDT { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> RedeemUserId { get; set; }
public string RedeemUserName { get; set; }
public string Note { get; set; }
public Nullable<bool> IsRedeemed { get; set; }
```

I added

```
public  virtual  Reseller reseller { get; set; }
```

to  get the reseller name with voucher

In action when I called

```
var model = (from v in context.Vouchers orderby v.Id select v);
```

an error was displayed

> The entity type Voucher is not part of the model for the current context.

What does it mean and how can I solve it?

Comment: Check the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634392/ef-4-1-code-first-error-the-entity-type-sometype-is-not-part-of-the-model-for

Comment: You need to **update** your model. Right-click on the model diagram and _update_ from class. If you use the **code first** approach then you might have problems because of the virtual so write it like `public Reseller reseller { get; set; }` this should work. cheers!

Comment: Is your model code first?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you haven't register entities in context like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Voucher>();
            // need register Reseller as well
        }
```

Google for OnModelCreating and DbModelBuilder.

Comment: it's like this now 

    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Reseller>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Voucher>();
      
            // need register Reseller as well
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

Comment: @AhmedNaguib please show whole your code with table/column attributes, database initializer. Make sure you use correct connection string (correct server and db containig all these entities). Make sure table names match Table attributes in your model.